# Backward slash missing from substitution in Scala

Tags: regex, string, scala

I need to construct some complex strings and for this reason I always use `"""`(triple quotes) as delimiters for string and regexps in Scala.

In some examples, such as this:

```
"""foo""".r.replaceAllIn("foo", m => """backslash\andsometext""")
// result = """backslashandsometext"""
// where's the backslash?
```

The backslash is gone form the result.

WHat is the reason for this? Shouldn't strings wrapped in `"""` perform **NO** escaping whatsoever??

Comment: I'm not sure how I was getting some of the results I got earlier, but my answer is flawed as pointed out. You should choose a different answer as the correct one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're supposed to quote your replacement string [this way](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.util.matching.Regex$@quoteReplacement(text:String):String):

```
scala> import util.matching._
import util.matching._

scala> """foo""".r.replaceAllIn("foo", m => Regex quoteReplacement """backslash\andsometext""")
res2: String = backslash\andsometext
```

Counter-example:

```
scala> "f(oo)".r.replaceAllIn("foo", m => """backslash$1\$andsometext""")
res3: String = backslashoo$andsometext
```

So dollar means group and backslash means escape the dollar.

Comment: so please correct me if I'm wrong. Strings wrapped in `"""` **are** indeed raw and no escaping takes places inside, except when used as **replacement** in a regex method, where characters like the backslash and the dollar have special meaning. And possibly in interpolations as well. Correct?

Comment: Yes. """foo""" is the literal with no escaping by the compiler.  s"""foo""" passes the literal to StringContext.s which processes escapes. """foo""".r passes it to Regex, which of course processes its own escapes. Same thing with replace functions.

Answer (score 2):

While the others have posted some solution the missed the why, indeed the triple quotes avoids the escaping:

```
scala> println("""backslash\andsometext""")
backslash\andsometext
```

But the problem is how `replaceAllIn` is implemented, it uses java features and especially the Matcher.class and the [`appendReplacement`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/regex/Matcher.java#Matcher.appendReplacement%28java.lang.StringBuffer%2Cjava.lang.String%29) function where there's this part:

```
while (i < paramString.length())
{
  char c = paramString.charAt(i);
  if (c == '\\')
  {
    i++;
    c = paramString.charAt(i);
    localStringBuffer.append(c);
    i++;
  }
  ...
```

Where `paramString` is the string you are trying to replace, so even if the triple quotes avoid the escaping problems you still have them when using the Matcher.class since it goes character by character and skips the slash.

Escaping the slash works because if there's one it takes the immediate next character (which is another slash) and appends it to the `StringBuffer`.

Answer (score 1):

> Shouldn't strings wrapped in """ perform NO escaping whatsoever??

This isn't true, the backslash is still an escape character.

```
scala> """foo""".r.replaceAllIn("foo", m => ("""backslash\\andsometext"""))
res1: String = backslash\andsometext
```

I think you may be mistaking that `\"` doesn't work within triple quotes.

```
scala> var str = """test\"123 """
str: String = "test\"123"
```

Comment: Sorry, this is wrong.  The backslash is interpreted by the replace method.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. My REPL was escaping most triple quoted characters earlier, and now it's not. Scala version difference or bug (different machines), perhaps. The OP should choose a different answer.

Comment: Interpolators also process backslashes, so `s"""Huh?\n"""` makes you say huh.

Answer (score 1):

The backslash itself is special and serves as an escape character. You have to escape the backslash with a backslash. Therefore, for every *single* (`\`) backslash you need *two* backslashes (`\\`).

```
"""foo""".r.replaceAllIn("foo", m => ("""backslash\\andsometext"""))
```